# Array Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, scope, global

I've looked around for hours and I honestly don't understand why this is not working. I though I understood scope, but I think this has something to do with the callback on the .popular method. Any advice?

```
var filters = [];  //Global

INSTAJAM.media.popular(function(popular){

    for (i in popular.data){
        filters.push(popular.data[i].filter); //Pushing to Global
    }

    console.log(filters); //Works fine

});

console.log(filters); //Empty array
```

Comment: Your method is most likely asynchronous.

Comment: who is calling `INSTAJAM.media.popular`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the reasons I can think of for why your second console.log(filters) would be empty:

1. `INSTAJAM.media.popular` is likely an asynchronous function (it calls it's callback sometime later probably as the result of an ajax call) and when you do the second `console.log(filters);`, the ajax call has not yet completed so your callback that populates the global `filters` variable has not yet been called or run.
2. `var filters = [];` is not really global.
3. There's another variable named `filters` within scope so you aren't actually modifying the global one.

Based on the structure of `INSTAJAM.media.popular` that takes a callback, my guess is #1.  Asynchronous javascript means that things do not happen in serial execution order.  Instead, you call something like `INSTAJAM.media.popular(fn)` and sometime later, the callback is called when the ajax call completes.  This means that code located immediately after you call `INSTAJAM.media.popular(fn)` cannot use the results of that call.  Instead any code that wants to use those results must be in the callback itself or called from the callback.

Comment: I looked checked off options 2 and 3, so it must be #1. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @MateiGheorghiu - restructure your code to work with asynchronous operations as I described in my last paragraph.  If `INSTAJAM.media.popular()` is async, that is the ONLY way.

Comment: Man, i'm sorry to be a pain, but I've never worked with asynchronous functions before. I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: @MateiGheorghiu - ALL code that uses the result in the callback has to be in the callback or called from the callback.  It can't be anywhere else.  You can't program in sequential fashion with async functions.  Instead, you have to put all the subsequent code that uses the results of the async call into the callback itself.  It's a different structure, but the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can reference `window.filters`